# DataTable Webmethod only works with thread.sleep

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, webmethod

I'm trying to serialize a DataTable return to use on a WebMethod its just simple like that:

```
DataTable dtResult = Occurrences.Search(....);
```

The thing is, if I, immediatly type

```
return dtResult.Rows.Count.ToString();
```

It will return "0".

But if i add just after the first line:

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
```

Everything works fine and the row count is 2.

Since when DataTable fetching is asynchronous? Another funny thing: On localhost it works perfectly, even without the thread.sleep, when i send it to the development server, screws up and only works when i type thread.sleep.

Comment: Can you make sure the query is executed without the sleep ? You could monitor SQL server and see how long the query takes. But as far as I know, fetching is not asynchronous. Could you provide the code of the search method (it doesn't look it is a DataTable method) ?

Comment: What's `Occurrences.Search` ? What does it do and how it returns the data? WebMethods can be async, you know.

Comment: The search method just returns a DataTable, and even that the query does take over 5 seconds, fetching shouldn't be async. I've never experienced that error before

Comment: Yes but Search is not a .NET method, which means it is either part of a framework you are using or internal to your project, which is why we are asking to see code of this method to determine wether or not the problem is coming from it. Otherwise, we cannot be of any help.

Comment: It does call a external DAL, wich does work to any sort of query on the whole system, I'm just getting screwed on this one. Added one more info on the question.

Stuff works on localhost but not on dev environment